# A counterexample concerning annihilator of modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $R$ module. If we have a submodule $N$ of $M$, we can define its annihilator in $R$ as 
$$ I=\{\ r \in R| rn=0\, \forall \,n \in N \}\ $$ 
Clearly, $I$ is two-sided ideal of $R$. We also define:
$$N_{I}=\{\ m \in M| rm=0\, \forall \, r \in I \}\ $$.
This is the annihilator of $N$ in $R$. $N_{I}$ is a submodule of $M$ containing $N$. Now I wanted a counter-example where $N_{I}$ properly contains $N$.

I have tried different examples but everytime I am having $N_{I}=N$

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:
$$ R = \mathbb Z, \ \ \ \ \ \ M = \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2, \ \ \ \ \ \ N = \mathbb Z_2 \oplus 0 \subset M.$$
Then the annihilator of $N$ is
$$ I = 2 \mathbb Z.$$
However, the submodule of elements annihilated by $I$ is
$$ N_I = \mathbb Z_2 \oplus \mathbb Z_2,$$
which is strictly bigger than $N$.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works . . .

\begin{align*}
\text{Let}\;\;R &= \mathbb{Q}[x,y]/(x,y)^3\\[6pt]
&\text{and let}\;M,N\;\text{be the ideals of $R$ given by}\\[6pt]
M &= R\\[4pt]
N &= (x^2,y^2)\\[12pt]
\text{Then}\;\;I &= (x,y)\\[4pt]
\text{and}\;\;N_I &= (x,y)^2\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

so $N_I$ properly contains $N$.